# background Images

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing app using the jquerymobile framework. I have to set the background image in my all the screen. But the image size is differ from mobile to mobile. I have image based on the iphone screen size.

how to set the width and height of the images ,controls based on the browsers resoultion ? 
how to detect the screen resolution of the browser at run time?

I tried to the  but that also did not work. I dont want to use repeat attribute Please help me..

Please refer the attachment.

THanks in advance

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
```

should do the trick

Comment: ah and of course there is also -o-background-size, -moz-background-size, -khtml-background-size

Comment: Hi roman, I tried the above things.But it does not work in opera mobile. Others are working fine. How to resolve this?

Comment: did you add background-size (no prefix) too? could be, that opera already dropped the experimental prefix on background-size

Comment: Thanks Roman. It is working for background images. I want to move the controls also based on the browsers resolution. How can I do it jquerymobile ?